# "for a walk to the seashore" or "to the seashore for a walk"

Tags: word-order, prepositional-phrases, adjuncts

Which of the following sentences is grammatically correct? Are both grammatically correct?

> I sometimes go out for a walk to the seashore.
>
> I sometimes go out to the seashore for a walk.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, but the meanings are different.

> I sometimes go out for a walk to the seashore.

In this sentence, the walk involves travelling on foot from home to the seashore, and then returning home.

> I sometimes go out to the seashore for a walk.

In this sentence, this could mean the same as above, but is more likely to mean that the walk is along the seashore. You could travel to the seashore by car, bus, bicycle etc and still say this, because the walking part is on the seashore.